# Displaying threads alternatively in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I want to display this two threads alternatively like that :

- Thread 1
- Thread 0
- Thread 1
- Thread 0
  ...

That's  the basic code from where I started, I tried with **wait() notify()** Methods but I couldn't get the result wanted.

````
class Task extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

                double dure = Math.random()*200 ;
                sleep((long) dure);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Task t1 = new Task() ;
        Task t2 = new Task() ;

        t1.start();
        t2.start();


        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        
        
    }
    
} ```
````

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve here? if you simply want to print their names alternatively, take out the Math.random() call when calculating the duration for sleeping. 
for everything else you probably need to add details about what you actually want to achieve in order to get help

Comment: @meaningqo i don't want that kind of results thread1, thread1, thread0. I want that each time thread0 will be followed by thread1 or the inverse.  I putted the math.random to give each thread an arbitrary time less than 200 ms to sleep.

Comment: The random time used "                sleep((long) dure);
"  makes the outputs  "random"

Comment: It's hard to really answer this, because there's clearly an unstated requirement: if you only want to print alternating messages, the simplest approach is to just use one thread. So -- what are you trying to practice with the two threads? A CyclicBarrier or Exchanger (both in java.util.concurrent) can do something similar to this, but they're higher-level than wait/notify. On the other hand, you seem to be okay not using wait/notify. So, you need to tell us what you're really trying to accomplish or learn here, with one level of specificity more than "using threads".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions:

1. Busy Wait

Each thread wait before printing. And release when the condition is true. I used [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) for `indexToPrint` to make this value sync for every thread.

This solution works with n number of threads.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class Task extends Thread {
    
    final static private AtomicInteger indexToPrint = new AtomicInteger(0);

    static private int threadNumber = 0;

    final private int index;

    /**
     *
     */
    public Task() {
        index = threadNumber++;
    }


    private int nextIndex() {
        return (index + 1) % threadNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {    

            for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

                double dure = Math.random()*200 ;
                sleep((long) dure);

                while (indexToPrint.get() != index) {
                    sleep((long) 10);
                }
                indexToPrint.set(nextIndex());
                
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

2. wait and notify

A bit more complex to understand, but no useless CPU use. Let's explain how the synchronized block `synchronized (indexToPrint) {...}` works.
The block is synchronized monitoring the static object `indexToPrint`. This object is static (common to every thread), so only one thread can simultaneously enter this block.

When one thread enter the block, if its `index` is different from `indexToPrint` then the thread is stopped with `wait()` making it possible for another thread to enter the block. Else, the thread name is printed, the `indexToPrint` is updated to next thread index and all thread are waken up with `notifyAll()`. Finally, it left the block.

All threads waiting are now awake, and the actual thread left the block. So one thread can try again to print.

It's important to understand that when a thread is put to wait and then notify, it runs exactly where it was stopped. Here, a thread can be stopped at two positions: before the synchronized block and at the wait call.

The `while` is very essential here. All thread are waking up with `notifyAll()`, so after waking up they should test themselves again.

You can find a good [documentation here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify).

The code is based on the previous one. With same use of `indexToPrint`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class Task extends Thread {

    static private final AtomicInteger indexToPrint = new AtomicInteger(0);

    static private int threadNumber = 0;

    final private int index;

    final private static ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     *
     */
    public Task() {
        index = threadNumber++;
        tasks.add(this);
    }


    private int nextIndex() {
        return (index + 1) % threadNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

                double dure = Math.random()*200 ;
                sleep((long) dure);

                synchronized (indexToPrint) {
                    while (indexToPrint.get() != index) {
                        indexToPrint.wait();
                    }
                    indexToPrint.set(nextIndex());
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    indexToPrint.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The busy waiting code is ugly, the second one is good. It would be improved if there was an explanation of what it is about how wait is used here that makes it give the correct result. (The linked article doesn't do an awfully good job of explaining it, I think.)

Comment: @NathanHughes Do you consider it clear now? Should I remove the first part about busy wait?

Comment: This is a big improvement. I already upvoted this.

Comment: Great! thank youi.

Answer (score 0):

The random sleep time can cause the unexpected result also within the main method making the main thread sleep between the start of Thread1 and Thread2 can help you to know who is the first thread that will start the print task , after that you should give the right sleep time inside the task to give the Threads the possibility to prints alternatively  .

```
class Task extends Thread {
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            sleep(2000);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
}

public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Task t1 = new Task() ;
    Task t2 = new Task() ;

    t1.start();
   try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    t2.start();

}
}
```